# Is it possible to wait and return when one of two condition variables notifies?

Tags: rust, mutex, condition-variable

Usage of `Condvar` in Rust is something like this:

```
let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(true), Condvar::new()));
//...
let (lock, cvar) = &*pair;
let _guard = cvar.wait_while(lock.lock().unwrap(), SOMETHING_HERE).unwrap();
```

Is there something that I can put in `SOMETHING_HERE` that waits in the right way? I'm thinking about the simplest way of solving this.

My idea is to have a third condition variable that waits for two variables related to the other conditions, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a third `Condvar` and remember to notify it each time you notify either of the first two.

Consider using one `Condvar` anyway. Since they can wake up spuriously, you already need to check the “predicate”, i.e. whether there have actually been any relevant changes to the `Mutex`.